# Is that Cohen Kappa score correct?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cohen-kappa

Is correct `cohen_kappa_score` outputs `0.0` when only 2% of the labels are not in agreement?

```py
from sklearn.metrics import cohen_kappa_score
y1 = 100 * [1]
y2 = 100 * [1]

y2[0]=0
y2[1]=0

cohen_kappa_score(y1,y2)
#0.0
```

or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculation is correct.  This is an unfortunate downside to using this metric of agreement.  If one class is predicted 100% of the time by at least one classifier, then the result will always be zero.  If you have a few minutes, I encourage you to try calculating it yourself based on the [example on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_kappa#Simple_example).

As [this paper's](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/15883903/) abstract puts it,

> A limitation of kappa is that it is affected by the prevalence of the finding under observation.

The [full text](https://fammedarchives.blob.core.windows.net/imagesandpdfs/fmhub/fm2005/May/Anthony360.pdf) describes the problem more fully with an example and concludes that

> ...kappa may not be
> reliable for rare observations. Kappa is affected by
> prevalence of the finding under consideration much like
> predictive values are affected by the prevalence of the
> disease under consideration.  For rare findings, very
> low values of kappa may not necessarily reflect low
> rates of overall agreement.

Another useful reference is [Interrater reliability: the kappa statistic](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3900052/) which advocates using both percent agreement and Cohen's kappa for a fuller picture of agreement.

Comment: What a great explanation and references. Are there any other agreements metrics that don't suffer from these drawbacks?

Comment: A couple of papers ([[1]](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9440903) , [[2]](https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0222916)) recommend [Matthew's correlation coefficient] which is [implemented in sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.matthews_corrcoef.html), but as [this figure](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0222916#pone.0222916.e051) shows it has the same special case where it is equal to zero. If it's workable for your application, I'd use Matthews anyway and just handle the special case.

Comment: Another commonly used metric ([AUC-ROC](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score)) is also undefined for this special case.  I guess I didn't really answer your question, though, so perhaps examine the other metrics available in the [sklearn user guide for classification metrics](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#classification-metrics)?

Comment: If your problem is as simple as the agreement between two binary classifiers, then you can just use something simple like [accuracy](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html#sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score).  It really just depends upon your application.